# Should the android back button be overriden

Tags: android, tabs, fragment

I want to go back to the last fragment in the back stack, so I want to make the back button popback the stack. Should I do this? and if so, should I override onBackPressed() or onKeyDown()?

```
@Override
        public void onBackPressed()
            {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,ABC.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
```

---

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ) {
        // do something on back.
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

My fragments aren't being added to the back stack properly for some reason

I am using this to try to go back to the previous fragment, but the order is acting strange. What exactly should I do to make the order proper?

```
@Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft){
        if(teamsFrag !=null)
        {

            if(manage.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
                manage.popBackStack(manage.getBackStackEntryAt(manage.getBackStackEntryCount()-1).getName(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

            //ft.detach(dataFrag);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer? No.

Long answer? If you have to ask, No.

You should set your fragments up using the fragment manager so that the back button does what you want. You shouldn't override the back button instead of implementing your stack correctly.

Comment: So then how should I set them up so that it cycles through the fragments?

Comment: @rasen58 why would you want to cycle through fragments with BACK button, that seems quite unintuiive from the user's perspective.

Comment: @fhucho wouldnt it be more intuitive, the fragments are in different tabs, so instead of pressing the tab, wouldnt you just want to press the back button. Actually now that I think about it, you're right, I wouldn't need it for that. But when the application is started, they click a tab that deletes all the tabs that were previously there and displays 3 new tabs in the action bar, so I think it would be more intuitive to press the back button to go back to the previous action bar layout.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to go back to the last fragment in the back stack, so I want to make the back button popback the stack.

This is the default behavior when you use [`FragmentTransaction#addToBackStack()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack%28java.lang.String%29) while adding new Fragments with the FragmentManager.